# Separate string by white space in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, associations

I have column with search queries that are represented by strings. I want to separate every string to different work.

Let say I have this data frame:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", "\t") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/my_data.txt")
    



data = df.groupBy("AnonID").agg(F.collect_list("Query").alias("Query"))

from pyspark.sql.functions import array_distinct

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

data = data.withColumn("New_Data", array_distinct("Query"))

Z = data.drop(data.Query)
```

```
+------+------------------------+
|AnonID|            New_Data    |
+------+------------------------+
|   142|[Big House, Green frog] |
+------+------------------------+
```

And I want output like that:

```
+------+--------------------------+
|AnonID|            New_Data      |
+------+--------------------------+
|   142|[Big, House, Green, frog] |
+------+--------------------------+
```

I have tried to search In older posts but I was able to find only something that separates each word to different column and it's not what I want.

Comment: Are you using Pyspark 3.1+?  if so, does this work `df.withColumn('New_Data', F.flatten(F.transform('New_Data', lambda x: F.split(x, ' '))))`?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Pyspark 3.3, but is does now work..

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Not error, It seems to be working but the output is the same

Comment: it should be a subtle difference if you are seeing with `df.show()`. could you double check where the comma is? or try `df.take(1)` and see in Python list format for better visual.  and you are doing this line after `array_distinct`?

Comment: @AmitBenDavid I tested Emma solution, it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

To separate the elements in an array and split each string into separate words, you can use the explode and split functions in Spark. The exploded elements can then be combined back into an array using the array function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split, array

data = data.withColumn("Words", explode(split(data["New_Data"], " ")))
data = data.groupBy("AnonID").agg(array(data["Words"]).alias("New_Data"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I got this error:
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'split(New_Data, ' ', -1)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'New_Data' is of array<string> type.

Comment: To overcome the error of applying the split function to an array of strings, utilize the explode function to convert each element in the array into a separate row. Then, apply the split function to each row, followed by using groupBy and agg to collect the split words back into an array for each row.

    from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split, collect_list
    
    data = data.withColumn("Query", explode("New_Data"))
    data = data.withColumn("Words", split(data["Query"], " "))
    data = data.groupBy("AnonID").agg(collect_list("Words").alias("New_Data"))

Comment: This could give wrong results of AnonID is not unique, maybe create a unique Id column and groupbY on that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the collect_list first and then use the transform function to split the array elements and then flatten the elements and then finally apply array_distinct. Please check out the code and output below.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([[142,"Big House"],[142,"Big Green Frog"]],["AnonID","Query"])

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
data = df.groupBy("AnonID").agg(F.collect_list("Query").alias("Query"))

data.withColumn("Query",F.array_distinct(flatten(transform(data["Query"], lambda x: split(x, " "))))).show(2,False)

+------+-------------------------+
|AnonID|Query                    |
+------+-------------------------+
|142   |[Big, House, Green, Frog]|
+------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: This @Emma solution from the comments above

Comment: Thanks @AbdennacerLachiheb for testing. this is slightly different than mine and it could be what OP wants. It is getting unique values (`array_distinct`) after splitting into words.